# Having trouble getting multiple command line arguments to run in windows forms

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, command-line-arguments

This has been bugging me this whole weekend...I'm a bit new at this so please bear with me.

I am trying to get this windows form button to execute the command line arguments I am passing to it but it is not working. It just stays at the working directory...

```
private void convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string safeFile = @textBox2.Text;
        string safePass = @textBox3.Text;
        string safeDir = @textBox4.Text;

        Process test = new Process();
        test.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        test.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        test.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @safeDir;
        test.StartInfo.Arguments = "sqltosafe.exe" + @safeFile + "-password" + @safePass;
        test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        test.Start();
        textBox1.Text = test.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

The application is supposed to:

1) One the "convert" button is clicke, it will grab the location of where the .exe is located.

2)Execute upon that .exe with the command-line arguments such as:

C:\SafetoSQL\SafetoSQL.exe (location of .safe file) -password (password)

I've been searching all over the web to figure out how to get it work but to no avail. I think it could be a simple solution and that maybe I'm a N00B at this but I am working on getting better.

Thank you all for reading and I hope you all can provide some input on where I should look for figuring this out.

Comment: What happens when you change the WorkingDirectory to point to the folder in which you are issuing arguments?

Comment: It goes to that folder where the .exe is located (which is good) but it doesn't execute the arguments in "test.StartInfo.Arguments"

Comment: When the process you are calling is invoked you will have a reference to the command line arguments. Make sure arguments are not running together, i.e. You don't have a situation like command="run.exe "c:\somefile.txt-password" "password".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you failed to add spaces and quotation marks to the command-line arguments.

```
test.StartInfo.Arguments = "sqltosafe.exe" + @safeFile + "-password" + @safePass;
```

Should be:

```
test.StartInfo.Arguments = "sqltosafe.exe \"" + safeFile + "\" -password \"" + safePass + "\"";
```

Or using a format string instead of concatenation, which is clearer and doesn't create intermediate strings:

```
test.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("sqltosafe.exe \"{0}\" -password \"{1}\"", safeFile, safePass);
```

The reason you need the quotation marks is that the user-supplied values may contain spaces and spaces deliminate command-line parameters.

You should also validate the user-supplied strings to make sure at the very least they are not empty.